# Erlang - Sort list of files according to postfix number before extension

Tags: erlang

I have a list:

```
["storage.pages/4532.1.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.12.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.2.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.3.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.4.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.5.html"]
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
last_filename(PageId)->
  Files1 = filelib:wildcard("storage.pages/" ++ wf:to_list(PageId) ++ ".*.html"),
  hd(lists:reverse(lists:sort(Files1))).
```

which at this moment returns  `"storage.pages/4532.5.html"` but I want it to return `"storage.pages/4532.12.html"`.

What are good adjustments I need to make to my function so that it always returns the element in the list that has the highest postfix number in the basename?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you don't need convert part of string to number. Just first do comparisons length of strings.

```
L=["storage.pages/4532.1.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.12.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.2.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.3.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.4.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.5.html"].
RComp = fun(X,Y)->length(X) > length(Y) orelse X > Y end.
hd(lists:sort(RComp,L)).
```

output:

> "storage.pages/4532.12.html"

Comment: And if there is another (new) file '4532.21.html'?

Comment: @TomRegner, sorry, I don't get what you mean.

Comment: I get it now - sorry for the too quick downvote; if you slightly edit the answer I'll be able to retract it -- I read the OP as allowing different prefixes, didn't realize they were all the same.

Comment: Thanks - I'm awfully sorry that happened.

Comment: Thank you @RimeBeliskner. This looks neat! 

Can you help me understand why this works in general? lists:sort compares two elements against each other, we advance forward the lengthier. Why does the X > Y part work on a list though? (it is apparent to me why such a comparison works with numbers, but not with a string)

Comment: @JonRiel, this is just a comparison for strings. They compare symbol and symbol lexicographically  so '0' < '9' and it work as numerical comparison when length are equal. Btw, there is a special [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp) for Erlang. You can ask there any question about Erlang.

Answer (score 3):

Efficient solution (in Perl world well known as [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)):

```
L = ["storage.pages/4532.1.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.12.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.2.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.3.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.4.html",
 "storage.pages/4532.5.html"].
element(2, lists:max([ {list_to_integer(lists:last(string:tokens(filename:basename(X, ".html"), "."))), X} || X <- L])).
```

As a function in module

```
last_filename(PageId) ->
    Files = filelib:wildcard("storage.pages/" ++ wf:to_list(PageId) ++ ".*.html"),
    FilesWVersion = [ {version(FN), FN} || FN <- Files ],
    {_, LF} = lists:max(FilesWVersion),
    LF.

version(FileName) ->
    BN = filename:basename(X, ".html"),
    VS = lists:last(string:tokens(BN, ".")),
    list_to_integer(VS).
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this but suggestions for improvements are welcome:

```
last_filename(Page)->
  Files1 = filelib:wildcard("storage.pages/" ++ wf:to_list(Page#page.id) ++ ".*.html"),
  Files2 = lists:sort(fun(X, Y) ->
    X1 = wf:to_integer(lists:nth(2, lists:reverse(string:split(X, ".", all)))),
    Y1 = wf:to_integer(lists:nth(2, lists:reverse(string:split(Y, ".", all)))),
    X1 > Y1
  end, Files1),
  hd(Files2).
```